# logging ip address for incoming request using log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am trying to log the ip address of incoming request. For logging i am using log4net 2.0.8.

I used Application_BeginRequest method in global.asax to save the ip address of incoming request. However it seems like not working for multiple thread for same user.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["addr"] = Request.UserHostAddress; }
```

logs look like

```
213.136.59.97 2018-11-30 07:35:33,561 [14] DEBUG Conference - Kitty: 
visaBoka LoadPrintTimeline end: 
(null) 2018-11-30 07:36:37,968 [32] DEBUG Conference - Kitty: Statistik 
btnVisa_Click started
```